# How to work with classes in javascript, as well as with a collection of objects of these classes?

Tags: javascript, c#, class, oop, collections

Good afternoon. In C#, I create a class, then from this class I create a class variable (or object). And if I work with collections, then I add my new classes to the collection.

```
class person{
   int id;
   string name;
   int age;
}
person myPerson = new person();
List<person> people = new List<person>();
people.add(myPerson);
```

As I understand it, in Javascript it happens in a different way. Here they do not like to create classes first, but directly add an object with data directly to the collection.

Tell me how Javascript is used to work with its own data types. What is the approach used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# is a strongly typed language, that is, you can declare a variable to be an instance of an object (or a primitive type) and then the language will throw an error if you violate this. So, a collection like this

```
List<person> people = new List<person>();
```

makes sense in C#. However, Javascript is a weakly typed language, that is, you can define a variable to be an instance of a class, but you cannot declare it. So, if you do something like this:

```
var myVariable = new MyClass();
```

then you have instantiated `MyClass` in your definition, but you only declared `myVariable` to be a variable.

In Javascript you can use arrays or objects as collections. Example using array:

```js
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}

var myCollection = []; //creating the collection
myCollection.push(new Rectangle(2, 3)); //adding an element to a collection
myCollection.push(new Rectangle(3, 2)); //adding an element to a collection
myCollection.push(new Rectangle(4, 4)); //adding an element to a collection
myCollection.push(new Rectangle(10, 15)); //adding an element to a collection

for (let rectangle of myCollection) {
    console.log(`${rectangle.width} x ${rectangle.height}`);
}
```

Example using object

```js
let myCollection = {
    'first': 'a',
    'second': 'b',
    'third': 'c'
}

myCollection.fourth = 'd';

for (let key in myCollection) console.log(`${key} is ${myCollection[key]}`);
```

In Javascript, `class` is a syntactic sugar for functions. Example:

```js
function MyClass(foo, bar) {
    this.myFoo = foo;
    this.myBar = bar;
}

let obj = new MyClass('abc', 'def');

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for such a quick response. For me, it is very valuable (without pathos), I could not find an answer to it on the Internet. In c#, I often had to create and iterate through collections of objects, and everything is obvious to me there. In javascript, I tried to figure out how to do it better, but I realized that I would spend a lot of time, so I decided to ask. Now I know how it is usually done. Thanks guys.

Comment: @СергейГорбулев it's great to hear that these were helpful for you. Basically you can loop like `for (let key in collection) {/* Do something with key or collection[key] */}` or `for (let value of collection) {/* Do something with value */}`. You can do this oldschool loop as well for arrays: `for (let index = 0; index < yourarray.length; index++) {/* Do something with yourarray[index] */}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can work in JS (since ES6) exactly as in C# :

C# code :

```
class person{
   int id;
   string name;
   int age;
}
person myPerson = new person();
List<person> people = new List<person>();
people.add(myPerson);
```

JS code :

```
class Person
{
    constructor(id, name, age)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

myPerson = new Person("p1", "Tom", 54); 
people = [];
people.push(myPerson);
```

Hope it helps ! :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for such a quick response. For me, it is very valuable (without pathos), I could not find an answer to it on the Internet. In c#, I often had to create and iterate through collections of objects, and everything is obvious to me there. In javascript, I tried to figure out how to do it better, but I realized that I would spend a lot of time, so I decided to ask. Now I know how it is usually done. Thanks guys.

Comment: With pleasure ! :)